# Form Validation: Let the comma as separator to be valid in integer field input

Tags: theming, forms

I'd like to let my users use separator (Comma) while entering values in an integer field such as price for instance.

I know that we can alter the validation of fields with [element_validate_integer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/element_validate_integer/7) API, but seems like that I can't get it working.

I appreciate any helps, thanks.

Also note that I'm using [Clientside Validation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) as well.

Comment: what you tried? have you written custom code to validate integer with comma separator.?

Comment: Not really I goofed around a bit, even tried jQuery which is not preferable way to achieve this. I wonder if there's a way to do it via template overriding

Comment: can you add more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have integer (or Big int) field you can't submit data with `,` in integer field and this means that you should strip all `,` before data passed to Drupal default form submit handler ( as you know before data passed to submit it must be  validated first ) So  the tiny and quick solution is  you set a custom  validate handler  that  called before Drupal node validation handler then in there try to strip all `,` ( manipulate data in your custom validation handler ) and then enjoy it.

```
 // in your custom module 

function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'your_form_id' ) {
                array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_mycustom_validate_handler');
}
}

function _mycustom_validate_handler($form, &$form_state)
{
$form_state['values']['your_integer_field']['und'][0]['value'] =strtr($form_state['values']['your_integer_field']['und'][0]['value'] , ',' ,'');
}
```

And if you also  want save `,` in database(!!!) try text field instead using integer field  and then with client side validation  Regex  Rule validate what you want.